# Moving an inverted hollow object from 1 surface to another over a gap. What happens to the air molecules inside object?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I am merely a curious student of physics and trying to understand some things that so far no one I have asked has been able to help me with.

In the picture provided. The dark colored half circle shape object imagine as a bowl. Turned upside down on a solid surface. I was hoping to find out what happens to the air within the bowl as it moves from surface X passing over the gap at fast speed onto surface Y. Is the air inside the bowl being sucked out into the gap or is it at fast pace sucking more air inside the bowl?

How does the air in the bowl after passing the gap react to it passing over the gap once no access to ambient air?

Looking forward to getting some light shed on this conundrum I have been seeking. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The friction between the air in the object and the surfaces (and the air in the gap) will cause a circulation of the air in the object. As it crosses the gap, some air will flow out and will be replaced by air flowing in.

Comment: Thank you for your response RW!

Answer (score 0):

Before reaching the gap, a fraction of molecules bounces back from the surface every second. When over the gap, those molecules go down into the gap. On the other hand molecules from the gap, behind the surface level, enters the bowl.

Supposing the same pressure and temperature, the consequence is that the molecules coming from the bowl and going downward have a $x$ component, and will pressure the right side of the gap. The molecules moving upward from the gap have a negative $x$ component in the bowl frame, and will pressure its left side.

So the net effect is an increase in the braking air drag for the bowl movement.